# How to hide a request field in Swagger with .Net Web API on GET Request

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui, .net-6.0

There are multiple solutions for hiding a model property from swagger if you're sending data via Body with POST request.

But in Get Request None of the solutions work.

For Example :
`Creating a new Attribute`, `Using [JsonIgnore]`, `[Obsolete]` etc.

So I need a method to hide this '**Skip**' Field both `Post request body` or `Get request query string`.

You can see the situation below.

This is how swagger looks like :
[image: This is how request looks.]

This is my model (I want to hide **Skip** field in Swagger):

[image: This is my model]

And this is my action :

[image: This is how I'm calling]

Comment: Make it internal?

Comment: see this [https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.WebApi/issues/1230](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.WebApi/issues/1230)

Comment: It's tagged as Duplicate but it's not. There isn't any question like this. 
The answer is [BindNever] attribute.